# How to explicitly send an EOF to an io.ReadCloser in golang?

Tags: docker, go, eof, blocking, reader

I hope this message is received by you in good health.

So there is this bug in a golang program I am working on where this blocking method, stdCopy.StdCopy() in the codebase can cause everything to hang. This problem occurs because Docker is continuously sending info to the Stdcopy blocking method, and a blocking method can only stop running if an EOF is sent to it. StdCopy accepts a ReadCloser type parameter which is how the blocking method reads info from Docker. Goroutines are also used right before the program enters the blocking method. In other words, the StdCopy blocking method is running in a new thread while the main thread is running in parallel to it. However, the blocking method now blocks the new thread which doesn't solve the problem.

What I am trying to do to prevent this problem is to explicitly close this ReadCloser in the main thread, and then send an EOF to the new thread which holds the StdCopy blocking method to forcefully stop it through a timeout error. This should stop the entire program from hanging since the blocking method is the reason why it hangs. I did this by storing a map of every ReadCloser I opened, and then manually closing them all in a specific method that is meant to run when our program is to be stopped. I'm not sure if closing the ReadCloser interface sends an EOF automatically (I checked the golang documentation, but couldn't find any info on it: https://golang.org/pkg/io/#ReadCloser).

I decided that I want to explicitly send an EOF to the ReadCloser just in case. However, how am I suppose to do this? I was thinking of using my knoweledge of channels and pass in an io.EOF through the channel into the go-routine where the blocking method is being run. However, io.ReadCloser is not a channel type, so I can't do that.

Does closing a io.ReadCloser send an EOF automatically? If not, how would you send an EOF to an io.ReadCloser so that a blocking method could stop running?

Please let me know if there is anything in my explanation that didn't make sense and you would like me to clarify. Feel free to also correct me anywhere where you think I am mistaken since I am relatively new to golang.

Thank you so much for your time, and please let me know any thoughts!

----- EDIT -----

**Here is some of the code I have written so far for better comprehension:**

```
        //Closing all of the ReadClosers opened to prevent blocking
        for k := range streamer.inputReadClosers {
            (*k).Close()
            //(*k) <- io.EOF //does not work since io.ReadCloser is not of channel type
        }
```

So for some context, streamer is just a struct that holds an attribute call inputReadClosers which is the map of pointers of all of the ReadClosers opened. I then explicitly close the ReadClosers and then the goal is to manually send an EOF to that ReadCloser.

**A bit of info on how ReadCloser is initialized:**

So I have one file that has a method with the following method header `func (streamer *LogStreamer) StartStreamingFromDockerLogs(input io.ReadCloser) error`. When I checked instances of where the `StartStreamingFromDockerLogs(...)` is used in other files, I found that a readcloser variable is passed and the readcloser variable is initialized in the following manner: `readCloser, err := dockerManager.GetContainerLogs(.....three parameters here…..)`.

Comment: So io.ReadCloser is an interface those holds the Reader interface and the Closer interface. The Reader and Closer interface hold the Read and Close methods respectively. I have learned about pipes in my C systems programming class, and I think the rule is that if the read call returns 0 when the write ends of the pipe are closed and all data has been read from the pipe. But I don't think I can do that here since the io.ReadCloser is not a pipe at least from my understanding of the documentation: https://golang.org/pkg/io/#ReadCloser

Comment: @Penelope Stevens My apologies for not clarifying which user my comment above was meant for (it was meant for Cerise, and thank you Cerise for your comment!). However, thank you @Penelope Stevens for your comment about how to figure out the concrete type! I tried the fmt.Printf() statement that you sent above, and got the following: `my io.ReadCloser is a *http.bodyEOFSignal`

Comment: @Penelope Stevens I added a bit of code to my question above to try and give a better understanding of my problem. You are right, I recognize that my question is looking like the XY Problem. Thank you for pointing that out, and let me try and clarify so that I am trying to understand the problem instead of only finding a solution to the problem.

Comment: @Penelope Stevens So I have one file that has a method with the following method header `func (streamer *LogStreamer) StartStreamingFromDockerLogs(input io.ReadCloser) error`. When I checked instances of where the `StartStreamingFromDockerLogs(...)` is used in other files, I found that a readcloser variable is passed and the readcloser variable is initialized in the following manner: `readCloser, err := dockerManager.GetContainerLogs(.....three parameters here…..)`. Perhaps `GetContainerLogs(....)` is causing a problem? I’m going to look into and keep you posted.

Answer (score 1):

This is really a comment, not an answer, except that it's too big to be a comment (and needs some formatting).

There are some fundamental mismatches here that make this unsolvable as stated:

- First, end-of-file, as represented by an `io.EOF` error for instance, is not something you can send *through* any kind of data stream.  It is a *condition that applies to the stream*, in which no further data can be received (at least at the moment—the condition could clear up in the future).
- Second, an `io.ReadCloser` is simply anything that implements the `Read` and `Close` methods (has an `io.Reader` and an `io.Closer`).  You cannot "send" an EOF *into* this.  An EOF occurs *when* its `Read` function *returns* an `io.EOF` error, as one of its two return values.  If some type *T* implements `io.ReadCloser`, and you pass a value of type *T* to some function *f*, and *f* calls its `Read` method, and this returns `io.EOF` as its error condition, then the reader for this *T* has produced an EOF condition.

As [Penelope Stevens said in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67864889/how-to-explicitly-send-an-eof-to-an-io-readcloser-in-golang#comment119953479_67864889), if we know the actual concrete type *T<sub>c</sub>* that happens to implement `io.ReadCloser`, *then* we might be able to find some way to convince *T<sub>c</sub>*'s reader to return an `io.EOF` error.  This in turn requires inspecting the source code or documentation for *T<sub>c</sub>*.  For instance:

```
type Foo struct {
    // unexported fields
    TemporaryEOF bool
}
...
func (Foo *f) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    // if we're supposed to assert a temporary EOF now, do so
    if f->temporaryEOF {
        return 0, io.EOF
    }
    // rest of code here
}
// implement io.Closer() here too
```

This tells us that a `Foo` object, which does in fact implement `io.ReadCloser`, can be forced into presenting EOF for some period of time simply by setting its `TemporaryEOF` data field to `true`.

This does not work for other items that implement `io.ReadCloser` since they have no `TemporaryEOF` data field.  This particular method of forcing EOF for some time during the operation of the program is particular to `Foo` objects.  **This is precisely the problem we cannot solve, because we don't have the right information: the code that makes the EOF condition happen is the code in the `Read` function for *T<sub>c</sub>*.**  Until you show us that code—or something that allows us to *find* that code—we cannot tell you how to make it produce an EOF condition.

Comment: Ahh, thank you for your clearing up my misunderstanding! I think the EOF design I have might not be the best then, and I might want to look into another strategy. However, I'll try to improve my question to make it easier for everyone who is kind enough to help me with my question. I have updated the post above with some code, but I'll try to find the implementation of the io.ReadCloser (specifically the Read function) and post that code for you as well. My apologies for not being clear, and thank you for your patience :)